An object key of a class isn't initialized or assigned in the constructor. Why does quoting it mute the error?
If I have this:
class A {
    a: string
} 

Then TypeScript will tell me that Property 'a' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
Quoting the key mutes the error:
class A {
    'a': string
} 

Playground
In my understanding there is no difference between quoting and not. So why is it the case?

In JavaScript there's no difference. But in JavaScript, as the error tells you, there's no property, either - in both cases it's just an empty class class A {}.

This is working as intended according to the PR implementing --strictPropertyInitialization, see ms/TS#20075, specifically the part about how the checks "only apply to properties that are declared with proper identifiers."  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jonrsharpe that really depends on your compiler options; class fields are part of JS now so the esnext usedefineforclassfields behavior will output class A {a;} and class A {"a";} respectively.  Not that this has anything much to do with the question, per se.

By adding quotes you're telling TS that it's a string literal not a regular class property, so it doesn't need to be initialized.

@jcalz that answers the question, but not really satisfying. Why does it only apply to properties that are declared with proper identifiers? Why isn't a quoted key a proper identifier? What is the difference between a key and an identifier?

@greekman so is it correct that there is indeed a difference in JavaScript?

@Ooker I believe so. TS is mainly just more strongly typed which is why it's giving you that error.

I'm not sure what to say about "satisfying". An identifier is something like a variable name, this is JS/TS terminology.  If you write const x = "y" then x is an identifier, but "y" is a string literal. Object keys can be identifiers or string literals. I'm happy to write up an answer where I actually explain this, as long as you agree that I'm not missing something about your question. It sounds like you do agree that, am I right?

@jcalz yes, it seems that you are not missing anything

This behavior is intentional. According to microsoft/TypeScript#20075, the pull request that implemented the --strictPropertyInitialization compiler option:

Strict property initialization checks only apply to properties that are declared with proper identifiers. It does not apply to properties with computed names or properties with names specified as string or numeric literals.
// Compile with --strict  
class Test {
   a: number;  // Error, not initialized
   "hello world": number;  // No check
}


In the type {a: string} or the value {a: ""}, the a is an identifier, whereas in the type {"a": string} or the value {"a": ""}, the "a" is a string literal. So the former receives checking while the latter does not.
Why this is intended isn't as clear. There are a few places in the language where bracket access (like computed properties) or string literals are exempted from checks as a way to allow developers to circumvent them, but obviously not everyone agrees with such decisions.
